# "I live in ..." vs "I'm living in ..."

Tags: tense, present-continuous, present-simple

Let's consider the following two sentences:

1. I live in Moscow and I'm a software developer.
2. I'm living in Moscow and I'm a software developer.

Do these sentences have some slight difference in the meaning or there is no difference at all? Which one in your opinion sounds more natural?

(The full context is [here](https://afiskon.github.io/pages/about.html))

Comment: I guess the progressive aspect conveys a sense of temporary occupations. In fact, it may mean "I am currently living there but I may go to another place in the future". However, I am not a native person.